# CodeIgniter 2.1 form_validation library not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, validation, codeigniter

I had a form which when submitted, either returned an error if there was one, or it subbmited the data to the DB table if validation passed, and it worked fine.

Now I wanna do the same thing with ajax, but the validation seems to always return false, no matter if I type in something or not.

My controller:

```
function add_new_category_ajax() 
    {
        // make sure it's the admin, else redirect
        if ( ! $this->session->userdata('is_admin') ) {
            redirect('admin/login'); 
            exit();
        }

        // load form validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // validate fields
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_title', 'Category Title', 'trim|required');

        // if validation failed
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) 
        {   
            // dummy var
            $data['dummy'] = '';

            // generate error message 
            $data['error'] = '<p class="errormsg">You must enter a category title.</p>'; 

            // load the view        
            $this->load->view('new_category_view', $data);        
        }
        else 
        // validation passed, add new category 
        {   

            // get category_title
            $ct = $this->input->post('category_title');

            // check if category title exists
            $cte = $this->mdl_categories->category_title_exists($ct);               

            if ( $cte )
            {
                $data['msg'] = '<p class="errormsg">That category title already exists, please choose another.</p>';
            }

            else  // it does not, proceed with insert
            {
                // prepare data
                $data = array(
                   'title' => $ct
                );

                // add new page
                $this->db->insert('categories', $data);

                // show success message and add another page link
                $flag = $this->db->affected_rows();
                if ($flag == 1) 
                {
                    $data['msg'] = '<p class="successmsg">The category has been added!</p>';
                    $data['aac'] = '<br><p><a href='.base_url().'admin/add-new-category/>Add another category +</a></p>';
                }
            }

            $data['msg'] = '<p class="successmsg">The category has been added!</p>';

            // load the view        
            $this->load->view('new_category_view', $data);        

        } // end else

    }
```

My ajax:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.submitnewcat', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('code');return;
        $('#ajaximg img').addClass('act');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#ajax").load('<?php echo site_url('admin/add-new-category-ajax'); ?>');
            $('#ajaximg img').removeClass('act');
        }, 200)
    });
```

Linking to `admin/add-new-category-ajax` is not a mistake, routes are set up that way.

Why does it always return a failed validation?

Comment: You are not sending `category_title`... that's why it is returning false.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add it as a parameter in ajax or what?

Comment: Man, where is the post method ?

Comment: @simo I am using load directly in the example. I am using the post method now as an alternative but then I use the automatic validation ability,

Comment: to make `form_validation` works you have to send a post method, if not it wont work, and I dont see how could you do that with `.load`

Comment: @simo doesn't load use post by default?

Comment: maybe I didnt explain myself correctly when I said (use post method), what I meant is add the parameter to make load use post method : `load('admin/url', { "category_title ": "myTitle" }`

Comment: Ohhh i see now what you meant by the category_title ": "myTitle". It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you need an extra parameter to make `load` uses POST method instead of GET method :

```
$("#ajax").load('<?php echo site_url('admin/add-new-category-ajax'); ?>', { "category_title " : "myTitle" });
```

The run method doesn't take a parameter if I'm not wrong :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

Comment: run method doesn't take a parameter by default, however I am using HMVC approach and it must be used.